# Is it possible to create a desktop application using C# and Python to create a Modern GUI

Tags: python, c#, user-interface

I've been looking into coding with different languages and have found that C# is a great language for designing modern GUIs. I like python; however, when it comes to designing a GUI with Python they tend to look pretty ugly and never match up to the quality of applications made with C# using WPF and WinForms etc. I've heard of IronPython but do not like the idea of using it. I wanted to ask if it was possible to design the front-end of an application using C# to create a modern looking application and then process all user-input and events through python (more familiar with Python and love coding with it!). If it is, then how? (Please leave a comment if you would like to ask me a question or would like from me to explain further. Thank you!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try pyqt5? PyQt5 is a comprehensive set of Python bindings for Qt v5. It is implemented as more than 35 extension modules and enables Python to be used as an alternative application development language to C++ on all supported platforms including iOS and Android.

Comment: I am currently using PyQt5 as a beginner but I can't seem to find videos or examples of applications made with it that have amazing GUI designs like that of C# and C++. Thanks though!